# ZFS Pools not mounted 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, zfs

The pool (two 4tb drives) were happily running in 14.10 but after upgrading to 16.04 they stopped.  Entering:

```
/sbin/modprobe zfs
zpool import Raid
zpool status
```

Everything at this point is mounted and accessible.  /etc/init/zpool-import.conf and rc.local look fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

OK - that was easy... but I don't know why (maybe because I skipped over 15.10?):

```
sudo apt-get install zfsutils-linux
```

showed a broken package and two zfs.doc packages pending with different versions.  I suspected zfsutils-linux wasn't really installed and

```
sudo apt-get remove zfsutils-linux
```

confirmed it wasn't installed.  So failing to have any other ideas:

```
sudo apt-get remove zfs.doc
sudo apt-get install zfsutils-linux
```

Removing zfs.doc removed all if it's dependencies, and the re-install was successful.

After a reboot everything mounted fine.

Comment: This also occurred for me on an upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS. ZFS wasn't natively supported back then so something obviously went wrong in the upgrade. Your suggestion above worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Experienced same problem after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.

The package zfs.doc appeared to be installed, but a:

> sudo apt-get remove zfs.doc
>
> sudo apt-get install zfsutils-linux

Fixed the issue.  Thanks for shareing.