# 16.04 LTS server. Trying to use zfs but it is not auto mounting after reboot

Tags: server, 16.04, reboot, automount, zfs

So I am running a fresh copy of Ubuntu Server 16.04 (Did install the Ubuntu-desk on top of it but otherwise stock)

I installed zfsutils-linux then using instructions from the Ubuntu zfs kernel reference site I was able to create a raidz pool. I made some file systems on it and started copying files to it.

Upon reboot the system doesn't recognize the pool at all. A "sudo zpool status" returns nothing.

If I do these two commands after it reboots(storage is the name of the pool):

```
sudo zpool import storage

sudo zfs mount -a
```

This will connect the pool and I am fine until next reboot.

When i do a normal reboot the root drive ends up being /dev/sdb

I have tried adding these two commands to the rc.local file but the drive names are out of order. I am assuming due to the fact my main drive is a slower older drive and probably takes time to spin up.

The pool drives are all consumer grade 2 TB drives and the boot disk is a consumer grade 500 gig drive. I use this computer as a test machine and as a backup to my other server. This server has currently 32 gig of ram and is a "9" series supermicro server motherboard with xeon processor so it has more than enough power to run as a home server.

I REALLY want this to work automatically and my other option is to put a delay before the commands but I have to believe it should automatically mount the drive somehow but I have not found how in the documentation or in any searches online.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible solution:  http://askubuntu.com/a/562462/231142

Answer (score 1):

First check to make sure it's really not mounted

```
sudo zfs get mounted
```

Then check if the mountpoint is set for the

```
sudo zfs get mountpoint storage
```

Then finally set the mountpoint

```
sudo zfs set mountpoint=/data data
```

Zfs works a bit differently than all the rest of the filesystems we are used to.

I think I created the pool without having a mountpoint already created with the same name.  I'm not sure if that's why it failed to automount.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your zpool, use the unique drive ids.  You can find these by going to `/dev/disk/by-id/`.  Drive aliases (e.g. `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`) can be shuffled/reassigned at boot, causing zfs to be unable to find the zpool.