# ZFS Pool not auto mounting after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, zfs

zfs pool imported automatically on boot in Ubuntu 18.10

Updated to 20.04, pool no longer imported on boot - I don't see any errors anywhere, but might be missing something.

sudo zpool import pool -- Works, fine.  Files are all there, no issues.

zpool update shows no updates required.
zpool status shows everything is ok.

/etc/default/zfs :: (cut most, but I think the important question is answered below)

# Run `zfs mount -a` during system start?

ZFS_MOUNT='yes'

# Run `zfs unmount -a` during system stop?

ZFS_UNMOUNT='yes'

Mount is to a specific location with the same name as the pool, so if I were running
zpool import pool
the mount location would be: /pool

/ is an ext4 volume on an ssd.  So the system boots and operates fine outside of mounting the zfs volume.

I am fully up to date on apt update etc.  Really kind of at a dead stop, not sure what to look at?

Comment: I know this is an older version, but perhaps some answers here might help? [zpools don't automatically mount after boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404172/zpools-dont-automatically-mount-after-boot)

Comment: No, it didn't help unfortunately.  Nothing in there seems to match my setup.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, ZFS was failing to import a zpool because it was on a cloud persistent volume that was not physically attached to the machine. I guess network volumes become available later than expected in the bootup process.

Running `systemctl status zfs-import-cache.service` after boot gave the following message:

```
● zfs-import-cache.service - Import ZFS pools by cache file
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/zfs-import-cache.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-09-07 18:37:28 UTC; 3 months 17 days ago
       Docs: man:zpool(8)
    Process: 780 ExecStart=/sbin/zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 780 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 07 18:37:26 ingress-zfs-2 systemd[1]: Starting Import ZFS pools by cache file...
Sep 07 18:37:28 ingress-zfs-2 zpool[780]: cannot import 'data': no such pool or dataset
Sep 07 18:37:28 ingress-zfs-2 zpool[780]:         Destroy and re-create the pool from
Sep 07 18:37:28 ingress-zfs-2 zpool[780]:         a backup source.
Sep 07 18:37:28 ingress-zfs-2 systemd[1]: zfs-import-cache.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 07 18:37:28 ingress-zfs-2 systemd[1]: zfs-import-cache.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 07 18:37:28 ingress-zfs-2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Import ZFS pools by cache file.
```

The solution was to patch the `zfs-import-cache.service` service file to include the `remote-fs.target` dependency:

```
[Unit]
...
After=remote-fs.target
...
```

On Ubuntu 20.04, this file was located at: `/etc/systemd/system/zfs-import.target.wants/zfs-import-cache.service`.

I think specifying `After=remote-fs.target` is equivalent to using the `_netdev` option in an `/etc/fstab` file (see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226453/78327).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more suggestions.

Try adding the pool to the ZFS cache file:

```
sudo zpool set cachefile=/etc/zfs/zpool.cache pool
```

Make sure the ZFS service is enabled:

```
sudo systemctl enable zfs.target
```

Also make sure ZFS import cache service is enabled:

```
sudo systemctl enable zfs-import-cache.service
```

I can confirm that my own ZFS pool is imported via the `/etc/zfs/zpool.cache` file on bootup.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: TY, helped me pinpoint this: not sure how to make it wait for sdf5 to come up, it does later.

11:45:55 server zpool[2393]: cannot import 'pool': one or more devices is currently unavailable
- server zpool[2393]: The devices below are missing or corrupted, use '-m' to import the pool anyway:
-server zpool[2393]:             sdf5 [log]
-server systemd[1]: zfs-import-cache.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
11:45:55 server systemd[1]: zfs-import-cache.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
server systemd[1]: Failed to start Import ZFS pools by cache file.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 here. I had problems about mount ordering. I got it working by following the instructions here:

https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2020.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html

8. Filesystem mount ordering

```
mkdir /etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache
touch /etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache/mypool
ln -s /usr/lib/zfs-linux/zed.d/history_event-zfs-list-cacher.sh /etc/zfs/zed.d

zfs set canmount=on mypool
```

After reboot the mount order is correct and I can bind mount directories from the ZFS volume.