# ZFS wont mount at boot because the log volume isn't ready yet 20.04.02 LTS

Tags: boot, mount, zfs

```
 11:45:55 server zpool[2393]: cannot import 'pool': one or more devices is currently unavailable 

-server zpool[2393]: The devices below are missing or corrupted, use '-m' to import the pool anyway: 

-server zpool[2393]: sdf5 [log] -server systemd[1]: zfs-import-cache.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE 

11:45:55 server systemd[1]: zfs-import-cache.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. server systemd[1]: Failed to start Import ZFS pools by cache file.
```

I get the above when starting my system.  Randomly it will time properly and the log drive will be available, but more often than not, it won't be.

Once it boots I can always import the pool via "sudo zpool import tank" without any issues at all, but since I have some VMs on there I want to start at boot time... This is an issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ZFS Pool not auto mounting after upgrade to 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294944/zfs-pool-not-auto-mounting-after-upgrade-to-20-04)