# ZFS pool doesn't automount at boot - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: automount, zfs

I have Ubuntu 18.04.6 server installed on a PC, and a zpool striped named **frnl** composed of 2 HDDs of 2TB each.
My problem is that recently the zpool isn't automounted at boot, it needs to run

```
alex@freenalex:/$ sudo zpool import frnl
```

to activate the filesystem. Otherwise, the filesystem isn't shown in the `df` command, and the `/frnl/` directory is empty. When I do the previous command, the `/frnl/` directory gets filled with its folders/files and everything works as I want.

I saw the thread [zpools don't automatically mount after boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404172/zpools-dont-automatically-mount-after-boot) but I'm not sure about the compatibility of their answers with my system (because it's an older system).

How can I automount my zfs pool at boot? do I have to install mountall? or if can't do a normal approach, Is there any alternative?

Comment: Before attempting a solution, it would be useful to know why the pool stopped mounting automatically in the first place. Has there been a recent software update or configuration change?

Comment: No, neither a configuration change nor a software update (AFAIK). I don't have a clue of what could be the cause

Comment: I remember now, there are directories inside the mount point (/frnl/) that are shared via samba and I edited the samba configuration many times recently , and added also new samba shares. Apart of that, I don't know any more configuration changes. And none software updates

Comment: Will there be any problem if I execute the mentioned command - (sudo zpool import frnl) - one time each minute, via cron?

Comment: Finally I added a cron job with `sudo crontab -e` and the line I added is `@reboot /sbin/zpool import frnl`. This way the zpool is imported every reboot and since then I have no more problems. Thanks anyway @matigo